# Advice on Java class

Tags: java, swing

I am starting Java class and this is my first code, so please be gentle ;)

```
//importing libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SongCollection {//class

//declaring arrays to hold user inputs
static String title[]={"","",""};
static String artist[]={"","",""};
static double length[]={0,0,0};

static int arrayindex=0;//declaring an index to keep track of arrays

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{//main method
    menu();//calling menu method
}

public static void menu() throws IOException{//menu method
    String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a menu option\n" +//taking user input and storing it into a string
            "1: Add Song\n" +
            "2: Search for a song\n" +
            "3: Edit a song\n" +
            "4: Sort songs\n" +
            "5: Print songs\n" +
            "6: Save songs to file\n" +
            "7: Read songs from file\n" +
            "8: Exit");
    int menu=Integer.parseInt(s);//converting user input into a number

    switch(menu){//going to the appropriate method depending on what number the user presses on the keyboard
    case 1: add(); break;
    case 2: search(); break;
    case 3: edit(); break;
    case 4: sort(); break;
    case 5: print(); break;
    case 6: tofile(); break;
    case 7: fromfile(); break;
    case 8: System.exit(0); break;
    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please choose a valid option"); break;
    }
}

public static void add() throws IOException{//add method
    if(arrayindex>=title.length){//checking if the array is full
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Song collection is full");
        menu();
    }

    //taking the user input and storing them into variables
    String newtitle=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the song title:");
    String newartist=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the artist of the song:");
    String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the song:");
    double newlength=Double.parseDouble(s);//converting length into a number

    //taking the variables and storing them in the arrays
    title[arrayindex]=newtitle;
    artist[arrayindex]=newartist;
    length[arrayindex]=newlength;
    arrayindex+=1;//incrementing one to the array index because one new entry was added

    menu();
}

public static void search() throws IOException{//search method
    String key=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your search key: ");//taking in the users search key

    for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++){
        if(key.equals(title[i]) || key.equals(artist[i]) || key.equals(length[i])){//checking if the key is in any of the arrays
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,title[i]+", "+artist[i]+", "+length[i]);//printing out the found key
            menu();
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Key not found");//if the loop completes the key doesnt exist
}

public static void edit() throws IOException{//edit method
    String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which entry do you want to edit. Enter a whole number between 0 and " + (arrayindex-1));//asking the user which entry they want to edit
    int edit=Integer.parseInt(s);//converting user input into a number

    if(edit>arrayindex || edit<0){//checking if they enter a valid entry that can be editted
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The entry you entered is does not exist");
        menu();
    }

    //taking new entries from the user
    String newtitle=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the new song title:");
    String newartist=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the new artist of the song:");
    String s2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the new length of the song:");
    double newlength=Double.parseDouble(s2);

    //storing them into the array replacing what was previously stored in that index
    title[edit]=newtitle;
    artist[edit]=newartist;
    length[edit]=newlength;
    menu();
}

public static void sort(){//sort method
    //nested loop to loop through all elements and make swap when needed
    for(int i=0; i<title.length-1; i++)
    {
        for (int i1=0; i1<title.length-1; i1++)
        {
            //storing title current index and title next into 2 different variables
            String t1 = title[i1];
            String t2 = title[i1 + 1];

            //storing artist current index and artist next index into 2 different variables
            String a1 = artist[i1];
            String a2 = artist[i1 + 1];

            //storing length current index and length next index into 2 different variables
            double l1 = length[i1];
            double l2 = length[i1 + 1];

            //comparing title current index with title next index using the compareto method
            if ((t1).compareTo(t2) > 0)
            {
                //creating a temporary variable to store the first variable and then swapping the 2 around
                String t3 = t1;
                title[i1] = t2;
                title[i1 + 1] = t3;

                String a3 = a1;
                artist[i1] = a2;
                artist[i1 + 1] = a3;

                Double l3 = l1;
                length[i1] = l2;
                length[i1 + 1] = l3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void print() throws IOException{//print method
    //looping through and printing out each element
    for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,title[i]+","+artist[i]+","+length[i]);
    }
    menu();
}

public static void tofile() throws IOException{//tofile method
    final FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("SongCollection.txt");//declaring filewriter
    final BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);//delcaring buffer
    final PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);//declaring print writer

    //looping through array
    for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++)
    {
        pw.println(title[i]+","+artist[i]+","+length[i]);//using print writer to write all 3 elements on one line
    }
    pw.close();//closing the writer
    menu();
}

public static void fromfile() throws IOException{//from file method
    final FileReader inf=new FileReader("SongCollection.txt");//declaring file reader
    final BufferedReader ib=new BufferedReader(inf);//declaring buffer reader
    String s;//string to hold read lines from file

    while((s=ib.readLine())!=null)//looping through the file while the lines are not empty
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,s);//outputting the read in data to the screen   
    }
}
 }
```

I have a couple of questions:

How do I make the Add Song interface have a button to go back to the main menu? similar of the other interfaces?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a full GUI for your program? If so, check out the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) which will have great advice on how to learn to do this. The bad news is that you'll probably have to re-write most of your code. If not, and all you want to do is to show a JOptionPane and respond to it, let us know, and please show us what you've tried.

Comment: *"Can I improve the code further?"*  A matter for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  BTW - please don't include noise like 'thanks' and a sig.  If it is that important for people to know who you are, edit your username and add info. to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1349643/user1349643).

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic neophyte mistake: your class is doing far too much.  Break things up a bit.

Have a Song class that encapsulates things together:

```
package model;

public class Song {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int length;
    // You add the rest.
}
```

Don't use arrays of primitives; use [Java collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) instead.

Separate out the UI stuff from the model class.  Make it possible to change UI without rewriting all your code.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use a Vector or ArrayList, rather than those String[] arrays. Otherwise, you're basically saying that the user cannot possibly enter more than three inputs. Even if they could, either you would have to resize your array or you would have arrayoutofbounds exceptions.

By declaring a Vector or ArrayList, you can just keep adding elements (whilst you still have available memory) and it guards against the array out of bounds exceptions you could incur with a primitive string array.